# ZipStorer not creating any file in Android c#

Tags: android, zip, xamarin

Hi i am using Xamarin with c# to make an app that can zip and unzip files so after a few tries i found zipStorer.

http://zipstorer.codeplex.com/

Here is my code

```
 ZipStorer zip = ZipStorer.Open(Convert.ToString(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory("BrSatisfacao/aaa.zip")), FileAccess.Read);

                List<ZipStorer.ZipFileEntry> dir = zip.ReadCentralDir();

                string path;

                foreach (ZipStorer.ZipFileEntry entry in dir)

                {

                    if (Path.GetFileName(entry.FilenameInZip) == "08.jpg")

                    {

                        path = Path.Combine(Convert.ToString(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory("BrSatisfacao/")), Path.GetFileName(entry.FilenameInZip));

                        zip.ExtractFile(entry, Convert.ToString(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory("BrSatisfacao/sample.jpg")));

                        break;

                    }   

                }

                zip.Close();
```

After a couple of hours the code is running fine and opening the zip and showing all in the console but no zip is being created... am i doing something wrong?

Comment: That code appears to be opening a zip an examining the contents.  I don't see anything there that appears to create a new zip file.

Comment: Give a read at the site of them, i get this impression too that i need to like Save(ZIP, Somewhere) but there is nothing like that, it says it doest it self and when u Close() the magic happens

Comment: use Create() to create a new zip, and AddFile() to add files to a zip.  You're doing neither of these things.

Answer (score 1):

Internally ZipStorer uses the character set 437 to do the encoding and un-encoding (line 85 in ZipStorer.cs):

```
    private static Encoding DefaultEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(437);
```

Xamarin does not include this character set by default when you build your application. As stated in the [Localisation And Internationalisation](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/localization_and_internationalization/) document:

*To reduce the size of the application, Xamarin.iOS doesn't include any specific encoding, and you have to instruct mtouch to include the assemblies containing the support for the encoding you need.*

To include the character set, add the **West** character set through the internationalisation settings in your application:

[image]
Ensure you check this for both **Debug** AND **Release**.

I could not get this to work for me when I was adding zip support to my application. In the end I rolled my own zip support by using the Java IO libraries but there may be a component available to add cross platform zip support.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me! But funny enough it was actually working on Debug mode... The problem started when I was packaging it.